# RSA version and its security with openssl

Tags: security, openssl, cryptography, rsa

I am looking for a strong encryption algorithm (already having generated a public key and private key).

I am using OpenSSL to generate RSA with 2048 bit key-length using an implementation in PHP. I just wanted to know how I can securely use the key for transmitting data.

What version should I use for RSA? How can I determine the version of RSA for the key generated by OpenSSL?

Answer (score 2):

RSA encryption can be implemented using different padding mechanisms. To be precise [RSAES-OAEP](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3447#section-7.1) and [RSAES-PKCS1-v1_5](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3447#section-7.2). These have been initially defined in different versions of PKCS#1, v1.5 and v2.0. I presume you mean this as "RSA version". There is also RSA [KEM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Key_encapsulation), which is probably the best mode to use for encryption, but it isn't used that much.

Both padding mechanisms however use the same keys. The only difference in keys is normally a key with or without CRT parameters. CRT parameters are used to speedup RSA private key operations 4-fold, they are generally included. The keys themselves do not specify for which padding mechanism they can be used.

It is however possible that the public key is embedded into a certificate that does specify different key usages. Even those however do not specify the padding mechanism itself.

So basically there is no such thing as an "RSA version" for keys.

---

If you can choose a padding algorithm, go for OAEP. Note that you should encrypt with the public key of the receiver, not a key from your own key pair. You should however use your private key to *sign the encrypted data* to make it unfeasible for an attacker to change the data in transit.

Comment: Thanks for reply. How can I sign using private key if form is filled by client end. I also could not understand: "public key of the receiver, not a key from your own key pair"
I am new to this, please provide some detail for this process

Comment: I am thingking as follow: Sending from client(browser) by encrypting the form data using javascript rsa library(with public key generated by openssl) and decrypting in backend php using private key of same pair